# Ubuntu 10.04 Live CD ok but HDD boot is not

Tags: live-cd

I have problem with new Laptop Lenovo T420 (I5), if I boot using live CD all drivers and every thing is ok, once boot from hard disk, the fresh Ubuntu installed by the same CD, all drivers
are missing. display,wired and wireless network.

I try to install it multiple time and the same issue, changing the CD with new downloadable .ISO

The same case after instillation, all it's missing drivers.

I will not mention the upgrade kernel since with live CD all drivers are working fine.

any advice.

linux83.

Answer (score 2):

Question answered by OP:

> Hi, I download the network driver manualy and upgraded the kernel. All went ok.

Answer (score 0):

When it is about drivers, some people recommend to install Ubuntu using the Alternate CD:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download

Comment: thanks for the link but what is the different.
i'm going to download the image from torrent link and will update you.

Comment: i try to install from Alternate CD but still the same.

Comment: Hi, i download the network driver manualy and upgrade the kernel.
all it's went ok.